# How do I debug by DDMS in android studio

Tags: android

The codes in the following can run but It have problems and I want use **DDMS** to find the problems.I searched about using the **DDMS** in this site and google and I can use **DDMS** now. But I can not understand that which line of my code have error.

I see texts in **LogCat** and they are for me meaningless.
please say for me how do I can understand which line of the my code have error?

the following code is in terms of grammar correct. but I can not run in my device or emulator well and after a short time, the program closes in my device and in emulator displays **No conversations** .

**Draw.java**

```
public class Draw extends View {
    Paint paint;

    public Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }

@Override
    protected  void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawRect(50,30,100,120,paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    }}
```

**Draw2.java**

```
public class Draw2 extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Draw2(Context context){
        super(context);
      paint = new Paint();
    }
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(50,30,100,120,paint);
super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Button button;
    Draw draw;
    Draw2 draw2;
    RelativeLayout linearLayout;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        super.onCreate(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.t);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        draw = new Draw(this);

        layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        draw.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        linearLayout.addView(draw);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                draw2 = new Draw2(getApplicationContext());
                draw2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                linearLayout.addView(draw2);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I see the following texts in **LogCat**

```
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     1.1% 84/Binder_1: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     1.1% 545/Binder_3: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     0.5% 36/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     0.5% 86/Binder_2: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):   9.8% 3532/com.android.launcher: 6.5% user + 3.2% kernel / faults: 167 minor
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     4.6% 3532/ndroid.launcher: 3.7% user + 0.9% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     4.6% 3539/Compiler: 2.8% user + 1.8% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):   7.6% 3518/com.android.phone: 5.7% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 73 minor
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     4.3% 3518/m.android.phone: 1.9% user + 2.4% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     1.4% 3525/Compiler: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     1.4% 3543/Binder_1: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     0.9% 3544/Binder_2: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     0.4% 3594/AsyncQueryWorke: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     0.4% 3599/AsyncTask #1: 0.4% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):   6.5% 3570/android.process.acore: 6% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 145 minor
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     5.1% 3587/Binder_2: 5.1% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     0.9% 3572/GC: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     0.4% 3570/d.process.acore: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):   4.7% 3186/bootanimation: 3.6% user + 1% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     6.3% 3196/BootAnimation: 4.7% user + 1.5% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):   2.2% 47/adbd: 0% user + 2.2% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     1.1% 3332/adbd: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     0.5% 47/adbd: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):   1.5% 3185/zygote: 1% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 60 minor
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):     1.5% 3185/zygote: 1% user + 0.5% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):    +0% 3627/ReferenceQueueD: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):    +0% 3628/FinalizerDaemon: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):    +0% 3629/FinalizerWatchd: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):   0.4% 3472/com.android.systemui: 0.4% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411):  +0% 3625/<pre-initialized>: 0% user + 0% kernel
07-06 09:07:50.264: E/ActivityManager(3411): 100% TOTAL: 63% user + 35% kernel + 1% softirq
07-06 09:07:50.694: I/Choreographer(3411): Skipped 225 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-06 09:07:51.214: I/ActivityManager(3411): Start proc com.android.music for broadcast com.android.music/.MediaButtonIntentReceiver: pid=3651 uid=10032 gids={50032, 3003, 1015, 1028}
07-06 09:07:51.274: D/dalvikvm(3185): GC_EXPLICIT freed 34K, 7% free 2365K/2536K, paused 8ms+18ms, total 190ms
07-06 09:07:51.474: D/dalvikvm(3185): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 7% free 2365K/2536K, paused 23ms+17ms, total 189ms
07-06 09:07:51.644: D/dalvikvm(3185): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 7% free 2365K/2536K, paused 13ms+14ms, total 170ms
07-06 09:07:51.974: W/ActivityManager(3411): Killing ProcessRecord{40ecb2f0 3472:com.android.systemui/u0a10023}: background ANR
07-06 09:07:52.614: I/dalvikvm(3651): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...
07-06 09:07:52.825: D/dalvikvm(3532): GC_CONCURRENT freed 188K, 10% free 3096K/3424K, paused 9ms+83ms, total 537ms
07-06 09:07:52.825: D/dalvikvm(3532): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 422ms
07-06 09:07:53.054: D/dalvikvm(3532): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 231K, 16% free 2991K/3552K, paused 159ms, total 160ms
07-06 09:07:53.214: D/dalvikvm(3532): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 10% free 3212K/3552K, paused 141ms, total 141ms
07-06 09:07:53.435: D/dalvikvm(3532): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 225K, 16% free 3114K/3680K, paused 158ms, total 165ms
07-06 09:07:53.504: W/dalvikvm(3570): threadid=3: spin on suspend #1 threadid=14 (pcf=0)
07-06 09:07:53.504: D/dalvikvm(3570): Temporarily moving tid 3624 to fg (was 0)
07-06 09:07:53.514: D/dalvikvm(3570): Temporarily raised priority on tid 3624 (10 -> 0)
07-06 09:07:53.594: W/dalvikvm(3570): threadid=3: spin on suspend resolved in 7174 msec
```